# Find covariance of a random process

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes, covariance

Let $Y_t = e^{-\alpha t}W_{\beta \ \exp({2\alpha t})}$, where  $W_{s} \  \text {is Wiener prosses,}  \quad 0\le t, \quad \alpha , \beta\in \mathbb R^1$. Find $\text{Cov}(Y_t , Y_s).$

Here is my solution. But I'm not sure and asking for verifications.

$\text{Cov}(Y_t , Y_s) = e^{-\alpha t}e^{-\alpha s} \min(\beta e^{ {2\alpha t}},\beta e^{ {2\alpha s}}) = \beta e^{-\alpha|t - s|}$

Comment: what is $W_{f(t)}$ supposed to mean ?

Comment: @Ahmad It's Wiener process

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $Y_t$ has mean $0$ and for a Wiener process holds $\Bbb E [W_r W_u] = r\wedge u$ we have that
$$\text{Cov}(Y_t, Y_s) = \Bbb E [Y_t Y_s] = \Bbb E [e^{-\alpha t} W_{\beta \exp (2\alpha t)} e^{-\alpha s} W_{\beta \exp (2\alpha s)}] = e^{-\alpha t} e^{-\alpha s} \Bbb E [ W_{\beta \exp (2\alpha t)} W_{\beta \exp (2\alpha s)}]\\
= e^{-\alpha t} e^{-\alpha s} \beta \min (\exp (2\alpha t) , \exp (2\alpha s)) = \beta \min (e^{\alpha (t-s)}, e^{\alpha (s-t)}) = \beta e^{-\alpha \vert t - s\vert}$$
Your answer is correct.